# How to use google drive api in my android application?

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I want to upload my application data to google drive.So I have to integrate Google Drive into my application, but I can't find any proper solution or source code for do that thing. So please if any one have full code of how to use Google Drive into android application than please help me.

Comment: please give me step by step solution, if any one have

Comment: There are tons of samples, information and full Android apps to peruse at https://developers.google.com/drive/android/ .
PLEASE do some research before you post

Answer (score 4):

First, a bit of critique. If you ask a question this way ('show me the magic trick'), it will get promptly down-voted, purged. It only shows you did not do your homework.

The other possibility is that you are starting and being totally lost (been there). If this is the case, let me give you a direction:

1. Study the 2 APIs available to Android, the [REST](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/about-sdk) Api and the [GDAA](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/intro). They do essentially the same thing, the selection very much depends on your app's needs.
2. Make decision which one to use. Pay special attention to the fact the GDAA supports only FILE scope, limiting the files/folder your app can see. Weight advantages/ disadvantages.
3. Study / play with the demo code for the API you selected. The links are in the docs you already studied (point 1 above). In case the official Google did not meet your needs, you may also look at the basic CRUD implementations of the 2 APIs [here(REST)](https://github.com/seanpjanson/RESTDemo) and [here(GDAA)](https://github.com/seanpjanson/GDAADemo)

As you'll see, you are weeks away from getting anywhere. And don't count on anybody here to do the work for you.

Good Luck