# How to upload and download using Google Drive API in Android?

Tags: android, google-drive-android-api

I learned the `Google Maps API` concepts, and now I try to learn the `Google Drive API`. I searched a lot and I found Google developers videos, but I'm unable to understand how to **upload** and **download** a file using `Google Drive API` in Android.

Comment: Please, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32820059/how-to-use-google-drive-api-in-my-android-application/32846189#32846189)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here Drive API for Android](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/get-started) get full details with step by step instructions.